# Using both many-to-many and one-to-many to same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a many-to-many association in EF Code-First (as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251794/how-to-have-many-to-many-association-in-entity-framework-code-first) question), and I want to use a one-to-many to the same entity as well. The problem is EF does not produce the right database scheme. Code:

```
public class A
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<B> ObjectsOfB { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual A ObjectA { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<A> OtherObjectsOfA { get; set; }
}
```

When I remove the ObjectA property of class B the many-to-many association is generated correctly.
When generated incorrectly, entity B gets 2 foreign keys to A, and entity A gets 1 foreign key to B (like a many-to-one relation).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have more than one navigation property refering to the same entity EF does not know where the inverse navigation property on the other entity belongs to. In your example: Does `A.ObjectsOfB` refer to `B.ObjectA` or to `B.OtherObjectsOfA`? Both would be possible and a valid model.

Now, EF does not throw an exception like "cannot determine relationships unambiguously" or something. Instead it decides that `B.ObjectA` refers to a third endpoint in `B` which is not exposed as navigation property in the model. This creates the first foreign key in table `B`. The two navigation properties in `B` refer to two endpoints in `A` which are also not exposed in the model: `B.ObjectA` creats the second foreign key in table `B` and `B.OtherObjectsOfA` creates a foreign key in table `A`.

To fix this you must specify the relationships explicitely.

Option one (the easiest way) is to use the `InverseProperty` attribute:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("OtherObjectsOfA")]
    public virtual ICollection<B> ObjectsOfB { get; set; }
}
```

This defines that `A.ObjectsOfB` is part of a many-to-many relation to `B.OtherObjectsOfA`.

The other option is to define the relationships completely in Fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
        .HasMany(a => a.ObjectsOfB)
        .WithMany(b => b.OtherObjectsOfA)
        .Map(x =>
        {
            x.MapLeftKey("AId");
            x.MapRightKey("BId");
            x.ToTable("ABs");
        });

    modelBuilder.Entity<B>()
        .HasRequired(b => b.ObjectA)  // or HasOptional
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);  // not sure if necessary, you can try it
                                      // without if you want cascading delete
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, for both solutions I get the following exception: `A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.DLL`

Comment: Correction: the fluent solution works (my mistake..), so thanks for that! Any idea why the `InverseProperty` throws an exception?

Comment: @Henkie: Does the application really crash? "First chance exception" is usually not a problem and only shown in debugger output window. Normally it can be ignored.

Comment: The application doesn't crash indeed, but the database scheme isn't generated. I'm using VS Express so I can't break on first chance exceptions.

Comment: The [InverseProperty] tag worked like a charm for me, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If table B has foreign key to table A then class B has navigation property to A and A have navigation property to `ICollection<A>`.
If table B has many to many relation with table A then class A must have `ICollection<B>` and class B must have `ICollection<A>`.

Try that, maybe this will clarify your request from the EF.

Comment: I forgot to add the ICollection to `class A` for the many-to-many association in my code example. It's fixed now.