# Entity framework: Unable to define 1:1 relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationship

I'd like to define relationship where **Student** can have only one favorite **Course**. I expect it would look like this in DB:

```
STUDENT
    ID    
    Name
    FavoriteCourseID
COURSE
    ID
    Name
```

How to achieve this with entity framework? I'd prefer to specify it just by attributes. I tried:

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Course FavoriteCourse { get; set; }
    public int? FavoriteCourseID { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

which gave me this DB model:

```
STUDENT
    ID    
    Name
    FavoriteCourseID
COURSE
    ID
    Name
    StudentID // how to remove this?
```

Note, that it may happen that several students have the same favorite class and therefore this is unacceptable solution.

Another question: what type of relationship this is? (1:1 / 1:N ?)

Comment: First - it is not clear why you need and ID if you have a Course. Second - One Student could have only 0 or 1 Class, one Class could be chosen by any amount of Students - so it should be 0..1 to 0..N here

Comment: It's one to many. And I'm not getting `StudentID` in `Course` table from your model (assuming `Class` is `Course`), so apparently the posted model is incomplete.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, the model I posted is incomplete. There was also many to many relationship between the entities. I assumed the problem was with the definition of `FavoriteCourse` relation. But as it turned out, the problem was, that Entity framework did not [recognize the relation correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228948/using-both-many-to-many-and-one-to-many-to-same-entity).

Comment: @chriemmy That's what I thought. So according to your comment I assume you have resolved the issue :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, I did. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To specify 1 to 1 relationship, it is assumed, that primary key for the related entity matches the primary key of first entity. Also you should specify a `virtual` property to related entity:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Course FavoriteCourse { get; set; }
    public int? FavoriteCourseID { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

And it will be `one-to-zero-or-one` relationship. Check this [tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).

If you will mark `FavouriteCourse` property with `RequiredAttribute`, it seems, that it will result in strong one to one relationship.

It will result in adequate database structure:

```
STUDENT
    ID    
    Name
    FavoriteCourseID
COURSE
    ID
    Name
```

However, if many students could have one favourite course, this structure will be a problem, as you want one-to-many instead of one-to-one. And you will have a duplicate records in database, because one course can refer only to one student. You have to think about your db design.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FavoriteCourseId")]
    public Course FavoriteCourse { get; set; }
    public int? FavoriteCourseId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you define one of the following relations:

1. Optional:Optional
2. Required:Optional
3. Optional:Many
4. Required:Many
5. Many:Many

Having Required:Required is not a usual relation, inserting the first entry with such a relation needs special treatment.

I Suppose you want Required:Many as in "Each student has one favorite course but many students may chose the same favorite course".