# Create relationship using a connectiontable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got two tables that have related items through a connection-table.

The connection table holds TableA-ItemId and TableB-ItemId. In my Entity-model I want ObjectA to have a collection of items from TableB. How can I achieve this using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your looking for is how to create a Many-to-Many relationship using Entity Framrwork. I going to assume your using Code First approach.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First

That project should get you on the right foot

or [How to have Many to Many Association in Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251794/how-to-have-many-to-many-association-in-entity-framework-code-first) Should be able to get you a quicker start. Good discussion in that thread.