# Code First Entity Model.. Joined Table without Primary Key

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, composite-key

im using Code First Entity Model with Web API Asp.Net
i need 3 tables in total
The First table`(Table1)` contains some information with a unique Id lets say it is like

```
string id 
string model
```

The second Table `(Table2)`contains some information about the user. lets say it is

```
string Id
string name
string company
```

now i need a third table. which would only work as a joining table and would contain

```
Table1 ModelInfo
Table2 UserInfo
```

but it is showing me an error that table cannot be created with out a `unique id`. but as my architecture is i dont need a `unique id`
what should i do?
or do i need to change my architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is general EF CodeFirst Many-to-Many relationship.
Suggested readings:

- [EF CodeFirst - Build Many-to-Many relationships](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/05/14/code-first-ef-4-1-building-many-to-many-relationship.aspx)
- [Composite Key - question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466374/composite-key-with-ef-4-1-code-first)
- [How to have Many to Many association in EF CodeFirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251794/how-to-have-many-to-many-association-in-entity-framework-code-first)