# Table with several one-to-many relationships

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have an EF code-first model with a table having several one-to-many relationships with other tables:

```
public class Note
{
  [Key]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string NoteText { get; set; }
  public string Author { get; set; }
  public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
  public Foo()
  {
    Notes = new HashSet<Note>();
  }

  [Key]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
  // other properties ommited...
}

public class Bar
{
  public Bar()
  {
    Notes = new HashSet<Note>();
  }

  [Key]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
  // other properties ommited...
}
```

As you can see, both `Foo` and `Bar` have their own list of `Notes`, but a `Note` belongs to either a `Foo` **or** a `Bar`.

When scaffolding the migration, EF creates a foreign key for `Foo` and `Bar` in the `Notes` table, which I think is not correct. I would like, instead, that a link table is created between `Foo` and `Notes` and another one between `Bar` and `Notes`.

Is there a way to automatically do this? Or do I have to manually create these classes in my code-first implementation?

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered in this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251794/how-to-have-many-to-many-association-in-entity-framework-code-first)! 
But to save you a little googling, you are getting a one-to-many association, which is correct. you want a many-to-many relationship in your code, so what you will need to do is :

in your Notes class:

```
public class Note
{
  [Key]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string NoteText { get; set; }
  public string Author { get; set; }
  public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I really want a one-to-many relationship since a note belongs to only one Foo (or Bar), and a Foo (or Bar) can have many Notes. Also, I don't need the navigation property from Notes. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: you can try [this link] (http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx) instead, you will need to use `.WithMany` function or the `.Map` one together with the `EntityTypeConfiguration`. The link has useful information. I haven't seen any way to do this using annotations.